# Eclipse-like comment formatting in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In Eclipse, I can format comments by selecting them and pressing `Shift + Ctrl + F`. For example, when I select a method comment like this:

```
/**
 * This method
 * does some stuff.
 */
```

and press `Shift + Ctrl + F`, Eclipse automatically wraps it:

```
/**
 * This method does some stuff.
 */
```

Is there anything comparable to this in IDEA?

**EDIT**: To clarify, I'm looking for comment formatting that also breaks lines that are too long into multiple lines.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The closest thing that you can get is `Edit` | `Join Lines` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>). You have to select the lines you want to join first.

To wrap long comments enable `Settings` | `Code Style` | `JavaDoc` | `Wrap at right margin`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately that's not exactly what I was looking for: Not just joining lines, but also breaking up a line into multiple lines if it's too long.

Comment: It would really be nice if you could set a separate margin for javadoc (I have my margin far right for long code, but for javadoc block text a smaller margin is much nicer) and if it would auto-join lines like Eclipse. JetBrans, can you hear us?

Comment: It seems very buggy: when wrapping, it always "preserves line feeds" regardless of that setting, so it is impossible to get block formatted text without manual formatting (using IntelliJ 11.1.3 here)

Comment: @AlexanderKlimetschek, you have much more chances to get attention if you submit bugs directly at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Reported: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90512 - According to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69770#comment=27-277123 they need to/want to rewrite the javadoc formatting for version 12.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I install `intelli jIDEA` , as a used netbeans, i want to use netbeans shortcuts in `intelli jIDEA` , for example `ctrl+r` for renaming, `ctrl+shift+f` for making code formate and so on, What should i do?

Comment: As of 2016 is this answer still accurate?

Comment: For me it is wrapping at around column 120, even though I manually set the right margin to 80...?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, it seems accurate for 2016.3. I wish I'm wrong.

Comment: Sadly this only works for javadoc. Eclipse can nicely format block comments inside a method.

Comment: I still was not able to format comments after reading this answer neither regular comments nor javadocs. After reading further I found out that it can work not only for javadoc but for all the comments. The following option should be enabled as well: "Settings > Code Style > Wrapping and Braces > Ensure right margin is not exceeded" as it's mentioned in the Ted M. Young's answer below. From my point of view, enabling this additional setting looks like a workaround for a bug which should be fixed in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: This is one of the few areas where IntelliJ is inferior to Eclipse.

Answer (score 10):

For Javadoc comments, you want to make sure the "Wrap at right margin" setting is checked. See Code Style > JavaDoc, under "Other". *However*, this setting only seems to take effect when you reformat the whole file, since a reformat of just the Javadoc (i.e., select the Javadoc, then do a `Code (menu) > Reformat Code...` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>) that exceeds the right margin doesn't force it to wrap. If I reformat the entire file, then it wraps at the margin as expected.

This seems like a bug (though one that doesn't seem to have been reported), since if you have to set the "Ensure right margin is not exceeded" checked, then selecting the Javadoc text and doing a reformat code does indeed wrap the lines. This setting is in `Settings > Code Style > Wrapping and Braces`. You can also do a search in the Settings dialog for "ensure right margin".

You'll still have to manually join the lines using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>

This might be worthy of an improvement request to JetBrains.

Comment: Instead of reformatting the entire document, try Ctrl-Alt-L after highlighting the *entire* javadoc, not just the lines you want to wrap. That worked for me (while selecting just the lines inside the javadoc didn't).

Comment: I agree that this seems odd that you need to have "Ensure right margin is not exceeded". My comment lines that were too long weren't broken up until I checked that.

Comment: Good find, @kghastie! The trick is selecting the entire JavaDoc comment.

Comment: And you can use `Ctrl-W` to select the entire comment - just press it enough times

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Existing comment will be reformatted when you do "Reformat Code" (⌥⌘L in Mac).

Answer (score 3):

@kghastie uncovered the key.

Steps:

1. Set the `Code Style > Java > JavaDoc > Wrap at right margin` setting.
2. **Select the full lines of the entire JavaDoc comment**.
3. Reformat Code (Ctrl-Alt-L or ⌥⌘L).

Lesser alternative:

1. Set the `Code Style > Java > JavaDoc > Wrap at right margin` setting and the `Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Ensure right margin is not exceeded` setting.
2. Select some text within a JavaDoc comment.
3. Join Lines (Ctrl-Shift-J) followed by reformat Code (Ctrl-Alt-L or ⌥⌘L).

   - Beware: This will leave all the selected lines joined even where you had paragraph breaks (`<p/>` or `\n\n`).

Answer (score 3):

The JetBrains plugin [*Wrap to Column*](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7234-wrap-to-column) is made for this:

[image: using the Wrap to Paragraph feature]

From the overview:

> Wraps text to the specified column width. Similar to the Emacs command 'Fill Paragraph' and Vim's `gq` (format lines) command. This is a replacement for the native Intellij Fill Paragraph command, which doesn't work quite how I need it to.
>
> This plugin provies two IDE actions:
>
> - Wrap Line to Column: Wraps selected text or the current line if no text is selected. This is useful for IdeaVim users who wish to pair the command with motions like `vip` (select current paragraph).
> - Wrap Paragraph to Column: Wraps the paragraph (multiple lines) in which the cursor appears. No selection is needed, and will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using IntelliJ 14 on a Mac, which has a Fill Paragraph command. Access it via the awesome universal Command-Shift-A action search feature. Works like a charm!

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: The command is definitely there.  Unfortunately, it does nothing as far as I can tell.

Comment: `Fill Paragraph` works. You have to put the cursor inside the paragraph you want formatted. I use it to format comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack, not a really good solution, but if you have a block of code that you want formatted like this and it's in serious need of auto format, because it's going over the 80 line max, or it's just unreadable...

You can just put `if ("foo" == "bar") {` on top of whatever you want formatted, and then and the`}` at the bottom of the if statement, to close it, and voila, your code should auto-indent, auto format, etc... Then take it out, highlight all of what you just formatted and press **SHIFT+TAB** to move it back 4 spaces and remove the dummy **if statement**