# IntelliJ wrapping comments in Javascript

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to wrap long comment lines in IntelliJ in javascript files? I have turned on line wrapping as shown in the settings below, but when I do a code reformat, it doesn't wrap the line.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Eclipse-like comment formatting in IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813662/eclipse-like-comment-formatting-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported yet on code reformatting, [added a new feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-5653), please vote.

Comment: is there a way to wrap comments automatically from a different menu option?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IntelliJ 14 on a Mac, which has a Fill Paragraph command. Access it via the awesome universal Command-Shift-A action search feature. Works like a charm!