# Intellij IDEA - different column wrapping value for code and comments

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Does Intellij IDEA offer a way to wrap Javadoc/comments on a certain column (say 80) and code in a different one (say 100)?
I'm running 2018.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ does not support separate wrapping configuration for comments and code.

There is an [open issue in  IDEA's YourTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114661) for it however this issue has been open for quite a while with no resolution as yet.

FWIW, there are some possible workarounds documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813662/eclipse-like-comment-formatting-in-intellij-idea).

Comment: Thanks. Workarounds are not really for me, I prefer having the functionaly entirely or not. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have Eclipse-like formatting capabilities in IntelliJ, just use the Eclipse formatter plug-in. You can find it here, and you can follow the instruction provided in the readme: https://github.com/krasa/EclipseCodeFormatter

Tested and working!