# IntelliJ: Copy & paste a text as comment well formatted

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, comments

I would like to know if there is a way on IntelliJ (v.2019.3) to copy a text, i.e. the following:

> Screening a transaction should return ‘REJECTED’ if the email id of
>   transaction is in blacklist and transaction was made within last 30
>   days. In all other cases, it should return ‘ACCEPT’.

and to be paste as comment well formatted instead to have a single *infinite* line as:

[image]

Comment: what happens if you mark the line and press ctrl-alt-l or cmd-alt-l on a mac?

Comment: @pero_hero nothing

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813662/eclipse-like-comment-formatting-in-intellij-idea settings/code style/javadoc/wrap at right margin

Comment: @pero_hero but on my release of IntellJ 2019.3 there is no more JavaDoc option:
To wrap long comments enable Settings | Code Style | JavaDoc | Wrap at right margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: ensure right margin is not exceeded]

could you try to go to Settings/Editor/Java/Wrapping and Braces/Ensure right margin is not exceeded

Comment: even if you mark the line and go to Code/Reformat code or ctrl-alt-L?